# How to change height of a Picker with SegmentedPickerStyle() in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

How do I change the Picker Frame in SwiftUI?

```swift
Picker(selection: .constant(1), label: Text("Picker")) {
    Text("Hello").tag(1)
    Text("World").tag(2)
}
.frame(height: 60)
.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
```

We expect the picker height to equal `60`, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 10):

We can do this by modifying hugging priority of backend `UISegmentedControl`, like below. After this the `.frame` modifier, like in question code, starts working as expected.

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

[image: demo]

```
extension UISegmentedControl {
    override open func didMoveToSuperview() {
        super.didMoveToSuperview()
        self.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultLow, for: .vertical)  // << here !!
    }
}
```

Comment: wouldnt this change all that use a segmented control type of picker?

Answer (score 9):

There is no direct way to change the height of the `SegmentedPickerStyle` picker but we can scale it using the following code.

```
Picker(selection: .constant(1), label: Text("Picker")) {
    Text("Hello").tag(1)
    Text("World").tag(2)
}
.frame(height: 60)
.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
.scaledToFit()
.scaleEffect(CGSize(width: 1.5, height: 1.5))
```

Comment: It just scales it up, which looks horrendous unfortunately.

Comment: This will scale text labels too, so totally not helpful...